# How can I link an Access tabledef to temporary table in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am porting a MS Access front end/backend application to be MS Access front end/sql server backend.

One part of this application (in the original form) uses VB to import a CSV file into a table in the front end, and then run various SQL statements to merge the contents of this table into some backend tables.

I figure in the new environment, because it more efficient to perform the merge process in a stored procedure, that my strategy should be

1. Open a connection to the backend
2. Create a temporary table on this connection
3. Create a tabledef in VB and attempt to connect it to this temporary table
4. Use DoCmd.TransferText (as I do in the original) to import the CSV file into the table linked to by the table def
5. Execute a stored procedure on the open connection which merges the temporary table data into the permanent tables on the backend.

I think I am successfully performing steps 1 and 2, but I am not sure.  I can see the temp table in SQL Server Management Studio, but attempting to open the columns fails with an error (it also fails with the same error when I use Management Studio to create a temp table, so I think this a Management Studio issue).

I am using the same code to perform step 3 as I use to link in all the permanent tables when I start up the application, but its this bit that is not working.  Finally, I have proven step 5 works by running it against a non temporary table.

The code I use for for this is as follows

```
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open getStrConn

    'First create a temporary table on the server for the web site leads
    SQL = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#WebSiteLeads]("
    SQL = SQL & "[leadID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,[Title] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Firstname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,"
    SQL = SQL & "[Lastname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[Sex] [nvarchar](10) NULL,[House] [nvarchar](50) NULL,"
    SQL = SQL & "[Address1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[Address2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[Street] [nvarchar](50) NULL,"
    SQL = SQL & "[Town_City] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[County] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[Postcode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,"
    SQL = SQL & "[Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[Allow_email] [nvarchar](5) NULL,[Telephone] [nvarchar](20) NULL,"
    SQL = SQL & "[Allow_tel] [nvarchar](5) NULL,[Cons_period] [nvarchar](20) NULL,[When] [nvarchar](20) NULL,"
    SQL = SQL & "[Procedure] [nvarchar](20) NULL,[Consultation] [nvarchar](10) NULL,[Info_pack] [nvarchar](10) NULL,"
    SQL = SQL & "[Source] [nvarchar](20) NULL,[Further_info] [nvarchar](255) NULL,[Callback] [nvarchar](50) NULL,"
    SQL = SQL & "[Date_added] [nvarchar](30) NULL,[Date_added_dt] [datetime] NULL,[Callback_range] [tinyint] NULL,"
    SQL = SQL & "[UcFname] [nvarchar](1) NULL,[UcLname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[UcPcode] [nvarchar](10) NULL);"

    conn.Execute SQL

    For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If td.name = "WebsiteLeads" Then
            CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete "WebsiteLeads"
        End If
    Next
    'link to the table just created
    Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef("WebsiteLeads",dbAttachSavePWD , "[dbo].[#WebSiteLeads]", getStrConn)

    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
    importProgress = 0.1    'Update Progress bar
    DoEvents

    'Import our text file
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Leads Import v2", "WebsiteLeads", txtFileName
    importProgress = 0.3    'Update Progress bar
    DoEvents

    'We are going to do the rest as Access stored procedure

    Set leadsRS = conn.Execute("EXEC dbo.LeadsImport;")
    importProgress = 0.9    'Update Progress bar
    DoEvents
```

But it fails at

```
        CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
```

with an error message "Could not find installable ISAM."

What is this error message, and why am I getting it

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be a temporary table on SQL Server?  Seems to me you're creating a temp with the very same structure each time.  You could just empty it each time the sp runs. You can link to a regular SQL Server table just fine, right?

Comment: I think you're stuck. I don't know of any way to link to a temporary table. However, HansUp has a good workaround in the preceding comment--make a permanent table (structure) in SQL Server, and treat its contents as temporary by having an SP truncate it just before the import (if your DBA won't give you permissions needed to truncate, you'll have to settle for delete).

Comment: I have found a way around the problem - I think.  The prime reason I was using a temporary table is that if two people are importing simultaneously they could trip up over each other.  A temporary table effectively gives a separate namespace to each user. But if I wrap the whole lot in a begin transaction .. commit transaction I can get that separation through the transaction processes

Comment: I forgot in the above to say the table I am using can then be permanent as HansUp has suggested.

Comment: Have you considered doing the temp table locally, on the workstation, and using a Jet/ACE MDB/ACCDB stored on the workstation for the temp table? In that case, the name of the table would always be the same, but it would always be specific to each user.

Comment: In answer to David - that was the old way of doing it when it was an access back end, but the stored procedure (step 5) above consists of joins with this table and several on the server, so that route is out, unless I want to haul large tables into the front end so it can do the join

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to not use a linked table at all, but instead have a passthrough query that returns the temp table. You'd likely have to write it on the fly, but once it's returning the correct temp table, it can be used as the Recordsource of a form or report.

I've not infrequently created saved queries that replace linked tables, though I've never done it with a passthrough connecting to a temp table.

Comment: Interesting - although I am not sure it would work - the stumbling block being the DoCmd.TransferText, which requires the name of a table.  From the reference "A string expression that's the name of the Microsoft Access table you want to import text data to, export text data from, or link text data to, or the Microsoft Access query whose results you want to export to a text file." which only allows the query on export.  I found a workaround (see comment above) so am using that.  I will be exploring pass through queries by dynamically creating a querydef calling a stored procedure later today

Comment: If you're writing a saved query, DoCmd.TransferText is not used at all. That's my whole point -- you avoid the issue entirely. In short, you seem to have missed the entire point of my answer.

Comment: I am either missing something, or perhaps you don't quite appreciate what I am doing.  DoCmd.TransferText transfers, using a specification in the front end, a CSV file loaded locally on the machine running the front end into the table we are talking about.  Unless I try and parse this file programmatically, TransferText seems the only way to load it into the table.

Comment: And what I'm saying is that YOU DON'T NEED A TABLE -- a Query can do the job (a VIEW). You can write the QueryDef on the fly as needed, and not need to worry about having a persistent linked table. The only reason you'd need to save the QueryDef (as opposed to assigning a SQL SELECT to as Recordsource/Rowsource to an Access object) is that you need to use a passthrough in order to have full access to the temp tables.

Comment: !Light comes on - I understand what you are saying now! Sorry I was being thick. I just created a passthough query for another part of the application that calls a stored procedure to use as a data source for a report. Had to do some mucking about to get from an ADO connection to a DAO.queryDef (see http://www.chandlerfamily.org.uk/2011/05/how-to-have-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-be-the-source-for-an-access-report/)